# applying css to font in table

Tags: css

I'd like to know where i have gone wrong, i want to apply font verdana to **"to change this font to verdana."**

I have removed contend from other table rows to make the code appear clearer. I have set the css styling to this section but when uploading the font does not change at all.

Code is:

```
<style type="text/css">
#form1 tbody tr td {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>


<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<form action="upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">

<tr>
<td><strong>Title 1</strong></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>To Change this font to verdana.<br>
  <br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</form>


<tr>
<td>
<!-- start here-->


<form action="http://www./cookie5payment/freecontact2formprocess.php" method="post"> 
<table class="freecontact2form" border="0" width="400px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span style="font-size: x-small;"> </span> <br /> <br /></td>
</tr>

<tr>

  <td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>




<tr>


<td><br></td>
<td></td>


</tr>



<tr>
<br>

<td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:center" colspan="2"><br /><br />
  <br /><br /> 


 <br /><br /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>


<!-- end here -->

</td>
</tr>

</table>


</tr>
```

Comment: put a dot instead of a hash before form1 in the css style

Comment: You have many problems with your code. The form starts inside a table row without a data cell. You have two types of break tags. You have orphan tags and improper nesting. Also, code shown here should be properly indented for easier interpretation. Simply put, clean up your mess and your problems will get simpler. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working as expected because you use the identifier `#form1` to target the table inside that form, **but** you start the table **outside** the form so the css selector can not find it. Change the order of your html as follows (i.e. switch the `form` and `table` tag)

```
<form action="upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1 id="form1">
    <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md2KJ/1/) to illustrate this